# How to make a jquery datatable use bootstrap table-responsive class?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, responsive-design, datatables

I have jquery datatable, and I know there is a "responsive" plugin to it, but I dont like the behavior as much as the bootstrap table-responsive class.

I should be able to just wrap my jquery datatable in a div with this class, but that doesn't seem to work for me. I basically want the table to scroll horizontal when too big.

I have tried wrapping the table in a div, that didn't work.

I have tried setting the class of the div that gets generated from the datatable, that didnt seem to have any effect either.

For those of you not familiar, bootstrap responsive tables scroll (see here):
http://getbootstrap.com/css/#tables-responsive

Jquery datatables responsive plugin, folds the table into a plus/minus (very elegant in some cases, but not mine)
https://datatables.net/extensions/responsive/

Comment: It really irritates me when people vote your item down but don't leave any comment or suggestion for improvement.

Comment: What exactly is wrong with the responsive plugin? You do not want to use bootstrap?

Comment: The responsive plugin folds the data into a plus minus setting, you can see the docs, I do want to use bootstrap (see the question), I want the table to scroll like bootstrap responsive tables do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding `<div class="table-responsive"></div>` container after the table has been initialized, see the sample code below:

```
$('#example').DataTable({
    "initComplete": function(settings, json){
        $('#example').wrap('<div class="table-responsive"></div>');
    }
});
```

The reason `<div class="table-responsive">` didn't work because `<table>` has to be direct child of `<div class="table-responsive">`, but DataTables changes hierarchy and the styles no longer apply.

Alternativelly, there is [scrollX](http://datatables.net/reference/option/scrollX) option that seems to be doing the same.

```
$('#example').DataTable({
    'scrollX': true
});
```

See [this JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qcmw5rh3/) for demonstration.

Comment: Sad to say, when I shrink there is no responsiveness action ..?

Comment: @davidkonrad, see the horizontal scrollbar when the view is shrinked. It makes the table pass the "mobile-friendly" Google test. I believe the solution with `scrollX` is even better versus container with Bootstrap `table-responsive` class.

Comment: Have not tried, perhaps you are right, but where should tablet and phone-users click or tap to see the whole row?

Comment: @davidkonrad, approach with Bootstrap `table-responsive` and `scrollX` is different that what DataTables Responsive extension does. If table doesn't fit user's screen user would have to scroll by gesture or with a mouse, but only table, and not the whole screen.

Comment: the scrollX option seems to work best for my table setup, but nice to know how to set that outer div's class via js, thanks a ton!

Comment: The initComplete solution was the real deal for me, because we have had some serious performance issues with scrollX, in our data tables. thanks!